# why flutter keep rending even through exists page using Navigator.pop(context)

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

Now my article detail page have some gif animation, I am load the article using [flutter html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) component like this:

```
if (item.content != "")
              Html(
                  data: item.content,
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                    ),
                  },
                  customImageRenders: defaultImageRenders,
                  onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, dom.Element? element) {
                    CommonUtils.launchUrl(url);
                  }),
```

when the article content has some gif animation, the article detail page will render all the time because the page will show the gif animation. but when I exists this article detail page using:

```
  void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_initialSwipeOffset != null) {
      final offsetDifference = _initialSwipeOffset!.dx - _finalSwipeOffset!.dx;
      if (offsetDifference < 0) {
        if (PaintingBinding.instance != null && PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache != null) {
          
          PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.clear();
          PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.clearLiveImages();
        }
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }
  }
```

then the app all page will rendering all the time with no stop. How do I know? I turn on the real device debugging switch.

```
checkerboardOffscreenLayers: showDebugInfo,
checkerboardRasterCacheImages: showDebugInfo,
showPerformanceOverlay: showDebugInfo,
```

I am confusing why the rendering will always keeping even through I exits the article detail page? is it possible to make the article detail page dispose completely? what should I do to stop the animation after exists article detail page?

I know maybe I should dispose the article detail page after pop, but I did not know how to do.

Comment: Where are you calling `Navigator.pop(context)`?

Comment: I am calling on gesture swip from left to right.@enzo I have added the code to question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely remove this page from stack try other Navigator methods like pushReplacment or pushAndRemoveUntil.

Comment: I read the doc and I know I could use `pushReplacementNamed`, the previous page could dispose automatic. But the detail page is a public page and has many entry, I could not know the previous page's name. @Ward Suleiman