# why the ImageStreamListener do not stop when load gif in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am define a `ImageStreamListener` in flutter like this:

```
ImageStreamListener listener =
        ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
      var myImage = image.image;
      Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.complete(size);
      }
    }, onError: (object, stacktrace) {
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.completeError(object);
      }
    });
image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(listener);
```

but I found when the `Image.Network` load a gif image, the `ImageStreamListener` will never stop to receive image notify info even if exit the gif showing page. Is the gif image(https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/mw690/006v119zly1gsu8ni6jbbg30a007q1l2.gif) loop play automatic cause the problem? The gif will play frame by frame and notify the `ImageStreamListener`. With a loop gif, this action may cause the render forever, and the App runs in stuck, what should I do to avoid this dead render loop? This is my full code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class LearnApp extends HookWidget {
  var gifUrl =
      "https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/mw690/006v119zly1gsu8ni6jbbg30a007q1l2.gif";

  Widget load() {
    Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
    Image image = Image.network(gifUrl, frameBuilder: (ctx, child, frame, _) {
      if (frame == null) {
        if (!completer.isCompleted) {
          completer.completeError("error");
        }
        return child;
      } else {
        return child;
      }
    });

    ImageStreamListener listener =
        ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
      var myImage = image.image;
      Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
      // debug here you can find the stream forever
      print(image.debugLabel);
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.complete(size);
      }
    }, onError: (object, stacktrace) {
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.completeError(object);
      }
    });

    image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(listener);

    var fb = FutureBuilder<Size>(
      future: completer.future,
      builder: (BuildContext buildContext, AsyncSnapshot<Size> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Image.network(
            gifUrl,
            frameBuilder: (ctx, child, frame, _) {
              if (frame == null) {
                return Text("dd");
              }
              return child;
            },
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("error");
        } else {
          return Text("dd");
        }
      },
    );

    if (completer.isCompleted) {
      image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).removeListener(listener);
    }

    return fb;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("widget title"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(child: load()),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to trace the code, and find when I using this code to add a `ImageStreamListener`, it added another `ImageStreamListener` before, then add `ImageStreamListener` created by my code. why would add another `ImageStreamListener`? where the another `ImageStreamListener` come from?

... I know one of then come from `MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter`.

Comment: Sir, why are you creating multiple posts for the same thing, from the past 2-4 days have seen your posts which is quite similar to related to gif getting rendered even after the page is popped out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why flutter keep rending even through exists page using Navigator.pop(context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570305/why-flutter-keep-rending-even-through-exists-page-using-navigator-popcontext)

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem.@OMiShah

Comment: I see, so the problem is it giletting rendered even after exiting the page, right?

Comment: yes, I did not know why the `ImageStreamListener` still receive image stream info even if I delete the `ImageStreamListener` or exit the gif render page, struggle for this problem for days. @OMiShah  the render will last forever which I did not want.

Comment: Will try to check the issue at my end and will let you know asap.

Comment: Ok, thank you for you patient and time.Any other detail infomation I am glad to provide @OMiShah

Comment: Not at the moment, will let you know if I require any information.

Comment: I fix it and now created a PR to the flutter html project, but I still not sure my solution is a good practice or not. @OMi Shah do you have time to review it?https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/pull/781